# How to add MessageConverter on Spring boot Messaging

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, messaging

How do I define a MessageConverter for a destination using spring boot? I have already defined my message broker and JMS Listener.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "new.clinic.queue")
public void receiveNewClinic(MyCustomDTO message) {

}
```

and my message broker

```
@Bean
public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
    BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.setBrokerName(brokerName);
    broker.addConnector(brokerAddress);
    return broker;
}
```

How do I add my own message converter for MyCustomDTO

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a `JmsMessageContainerFactory` and configure it accordingly. Spring Boot creates one for you but you can create as much instances as you want with your own customizations and refer them using the `containerFactory` of the `@JmsListener` annotation.

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
  DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
  factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
  factory.setMessageConverter(yourMessageConverter());
  // .. other settings
  return factory;
}
```

Note that the bean name here is the default name so you don't need to specify a `connectionFactory` attribute.

Spring Boot 1.4 will [auto-detect your `MessageConverter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/4284) and assign it to the default factory it auto-creates for you.

Comment: Will I have to change anything if I want to have multiple connection factories ? and connection factory with multiple Converters

Comment: With this set up, my "CusomMessageConverter()" is not getting detected when @JmsListener(connectionFactory="someListerFactoryThatShouldHaveCusomMessageConverter"). I have to explicitly wire and use the converter. Any pointers?

Comment: Yes. You are using a custom factory, not the default one Spring Boot has auto-configured  for you. Perhaps you could create a separate question for it?

Answer (score 0):

You could just define a converter like this

```
@Component
public MyConverter implements MessageConverter {
    @Override
    ...toMessage(...)

    @Override
    ...fromMessage(...)
```

Because you have it annotated with @Component you don't need to define either JmsTemplate (to set the converter on it for sending) or define DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.

Realise though, that if you do define those two classes, you have to set the converter onto both as suggested by Stephane